# Internet Explorer Javascript is not executed

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools

I'm currently facing a strange problem with a javascript block and internet explorer 9.
When I load the page the document ready function is not executed, actually it seems as no javascript at all is executed. When I reload the page a few times finally the script block is executed. I could not find any pattern when the script is executed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
              console.log("ie test - start");
              $("#id_project").select2({ width: 'resolve' });
              $("#id_year").select2({ width: 'resolve' });
              $("#id_month").select2({ width: 'resolve' });
              $("#id_purchase_order_membership").select2({ width: 'resolve' });
              $("#id_action").select2({ width: 'resolve' });
              console.log("ie test - end");
            });

        $( document ).ajaxStop( function() {
              $("#id_project").select2({ width: 'resolve' });
              $("#id_year").select2({ width: 'resolve' });
              $("#id_month").select2({ width: 'resolve' });
              $("#id_purchase_order_membership").select2({ width: 'resolve' });
              $("#id_action").select2({ width: 'resolve' });
        });
    </script>
```

More strangely, when I start the developer tools of IE the script gets executed. It seems as I trigger something in IE with the start of the developer tools that lets IE remember that there is some js to be executed. Very strange. I will try to deploy an example script in the next days, as I understand that it will not be easy to help for such a strange problem. My test deployment is currently running in a login only site. Anyhow, maybe someone has faced the same issue..

Comment: If I remember correctly, the `console` object is only available when dev tools are opened. Try removing the `console.log` line.

Comment: Thanks, yes that was the issue.

Comment: Yup, console.log() is flaky in IE (in my experience). Loading a page with console.log() when dev tools are closed will fail (in IE8 at least). Loading it with dev tools is open works fine. There's probably some fringe cases I'm not aware of it, but for testing in IE, get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge

```
 console.log();
```

is not working in IE. Remove these lines and try then

Comment: @Andreas in some versions of IE the `console` object is only available when the dev tools is open. Don't leave the `console.log` lines in your production code.

Comment: @nbrooks Me: _It's working but only when the dev tools are open_ You: _in some versions of IE the console object is only available when the dev tools is open_ - I'm confused^^

Comment: Thanks. I will remove all the console.log calls and see whether something changes. Strange thing for me is that the code is sometimes executed and sometimes not, even with closed dev tools.

Comment: That solved my issue. First I tried to wrap the console into a if block ( if (console) { console.log(".."); } but only removing all console references solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @andreas oops, thought you were OP. That was for Tom `:)`

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to enclose your code in `try-catch` blocks. Javascript just crashes on error and terminates all scripts that come after that.